# Предложный падеж слова "вызов"

Tags: грамматика, падежи

В словосочетании "по прибытии" слово "прибытие" в предложном падеже. О чём? О прибытии.
Почему слово "вызов" (в предложном падеже "о вызове") в словосочетании "по вызову" не пишется по аналогии, соответственно "по вызове"?

Answer (score 2):

В словосочетании "по прибытии" существительное "прибытие" стоит в предложном падеже. Но предложный падеж здесь имеет **временное значение** 
 (когда?), а не изъяснительное (о чем?).

Поэтому для обозначения временного значения  используется выражение
 ***по получении вызова.***

Пояснение

Не для всех существительных  возможно определить на слух **временное значение предлога ПО,** который обычно используется в Д.п., в частности это касается существительного ***вызов***.

Формы "по вызове" не существует в языке (есть только по вызову, то есть в соответствии с вызовом (Д.п.). Для сравнения: существует форма "по приезде". Вероятно, это объясняется тем,что в глаголе "вызвать" не просматривается узнаваемое временное значение, как в словах прибыть, приехать, окончить (когда?).

Поэтому в этом случае используется **вспомогательная**  падежная форма **«по получении».**

Пример: Реквизиты для перечисления взноса направляются участнику **по получении заявки.** [ «Стройнаука»: конкурс лучших учёных // «Строительство», 2003.05.26]

Answer (score 0):

Не очень понял вопрос... Но попробую.

> Почему слово "вызов" (в предложном падеже "о вызове") в словосочетании
>   "по вызову"

"По вызову" - это дательный падеж. (по "чему").

> не пишется по аналогии, соответственно "по вызове"?

"По вызове" в предложном так бы и писалось. Но где вы найдете ситуацию, которая бы требовала предложного падежа с предлогом "по" именно со словом "вызов"?

В общих словах. 
Предлог "по" в сочетании с предложным падежом в современном языке возможен только в некоторых более или менее устоявшихся конструкциях и только в значении "после"  (без оттенка причинности). Если значения "после" нет или имеет место явный оттенок причинности (это как раз случай "по вызову"), то требуется падеж дательный.

Вот здесь все это подробно расписано. 
https://popravilam.com/blog/058-po-pribytii-po-okonchanii-po-priezde.html

Comment: Я вот совершенно свободно могу сказать _по вызове_: «Ждите в очереди, по вызове заходите». Грустно, что это не по правилам :(

Answer (score 0):

Одинаковые предлоги не дают оснований усматривать *общие признаки* (грамматические или смысловые) у выражений "**по прибытии**" (предложный падеж) и "**по вызову**" (дательный). Первое указывает на момент времени, с наступлением которого что-то происходит (**сразу после** прибытия будет то-то), второе - на побудительную причину, основание другого действия (**в случае, если** вызовут, будет так-то). Соответственно, нет и аналогии в написании.